# Braintree/Javascript: How do I get access to previous customer's billing address?

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am trying to load previous customers' billing info (address) into editable fields on their account page.  I am using the Javascript v3 client implementation of braintree and use their Drop-in UI .  I am making a call to a server on the backend (backend team is separate from my company) of our app sending them the user email and the response has a clientToken that I take and use to create the Braintree instance.
Where is this customer billing info available that I can use to populate these fields?  Is it in a payload that client can consume or is there work that the backend needs to take care of this.

Comment: Can you update your question with some specifics? What version of Braintree's JS SDK are you using? Do you have a server-side integration with Braintree? If so, what version SDK are you using? Can you provide your code and walk us through your issue? For more information on what makes a good question, check out [Stack Overflow's guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @hollabaq done -- edited with more info.  My apologies